# Add If-None-Match header

Tags: varnish

For the url /foo, my backend returns:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
ETag: someetag
```

The cache-control directive is intended for the browser (which mustn't cache the response), I'd like varnish to cache the response and for subsequent requests to always hit the backend with a `If-None-Match: someetag` header, and if the backend returns 304, return a cached object.